# htaccess rewrite slash in url parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a PHP file that accepts two URL-parameters, a "fileUrl" and a "token".
When using it, it looks something like this:
`/getfile.php?token=randomtoken&fileUrl=media/streams.mpd`
However, i had difficulties rewriting the URL to the following format in .htaccess:
`/randomtoken/media/streams.mpd`
I believe this doesn't work due to the slash in "media/streams.mpd".
When removing the slash, it works. However, the slash is needed due to the use of different subfolders.

I ended up with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /getfile.php?token=$1&fileUrl=$2 [QSA,L]
```

but this unfortunately didn't work, and as I said, it only works without the slash.

Could someone help me out, is it possible to do this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I have considered URL-encoding the "fileUrl", but this didn't work well with mpd files, which are segmented video manifests that have a lot of files in the same folder.

Comment: What is your understanding of the regex `[^/]+`? What are the critieria for `fileUrl`? Is it everything in the URL-path after the `randomtoken/`? Or should it only match certain "files"? And what about `randomtoken` - can it literally be anything-except-slash as the regex suggests or is it more restrictive than that? Currently, your regex matches `<anything>/<anything-except-slash>/<anything-except-slash>`, which is likely far too general.

Comment: Your matching pattern is wrong. Instead of `([^/]+)/([^/]+)$` it should be something like `^/?([^/]+)/(.+)/?$`. So that it accepts anything as second part of the requested URL, even if it contains a slash.

Comment: @MrWhite: Hi, sorry for the confusion and thanks for your answer. I was quite unclear, the `randomtoken` is not actually the string used but rather it is a variable base64 json string, like: `eyJpcCI6IjE5Mi4xNjguMTc4LjEiLCJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE2ODk4NjM2OTJ9`
This is what a url with token could look like: `/eyJpcCI6IjE5Mi4xNjguMTc4LjEiLCJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE2ODk4NjM2OTJ9/media/streams.mpd`
And yes, just getting everything after the token would be perfect.

Comment: @arkascha: Thanks I can indeed access the php file now! However, after using this, the PHP file doesn't seem able to read the url parameters at all. What could I be doing wrong? Right now I have:
```Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/(.+)/?$ /getfile.php?token=$1&fileUrl=$2 [QSA,L]```

Comment: **Maybe I should have said this before, but this isn't in the root of my web server, but rather it is three subfolders "deep". Could this be the problem?**

Comment: If the rule is successfully rewriting to `/getfile.php` (in the web root) then the URL parameters should also be present. What other directives do you have in the `.htaccess` file? So, the `.htaccess` file is in `/<dir1>/<dir2>/<dir3>/.htaccess` and the requested URL is of the form `/<dir1>/<dir2>/<dir3>/randomtoken/media/streams.mpd`, but `getfile.php` is in the root?

Comment: @MrWhite: Thank you so much for your help! I was really confused with the subfolders, and you made me realize that.  I fixed it by naming the subfolders in the .htaccess, like this:
```Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/(.+)/?$ /subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/getfile.php?token=$1&fileUrl=$2 [L]
```

Comment: If the `.htaccess` file and `getfile.php` are located in `/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3` then you don't need to name all the subfolders in the _substitution_ string, just remove the slash prefix. ie. `getfile.php?token=$1&fileUrl=$2`. (But if that was the case, how was `getfile.php` being called at all before? Unless you had a duplicate file in the root?)

Comment: Thanks, removing the slash prefix works absolutely perfectly!
I didn't have a duplicate in the root, but it seemed that way because I confused the error message that came up while using the misconfigured `.htaccess` with an error message the PHP file gives when it doesn't get any URL parameters. That's just stupidity on my part...

Comment: OK, given all that the matching pattern can also be simplified, you can remove the leading optional slash: `^([^/]+)/(.+)/?$`. I like to put it in so that the rule can get applied without changes in the central http server's host configuration _OR_ in a _distributed_ configuration file (".htaccess"). That does not make sense in such a distributed file burried deep inside the folder hierarchy. Which is questionable anyway. If you have access to the central configuration you should prefer that instead anyway. Various reasons.